# Positional arguments in function seem to "overlap" when passing a tuple as an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tuples

I recently came acoss the following code:

```
info = ([
                ["id", "name", "price", "quantity"],
                [24351, "pen", 2.41, 500],
                [None, "pencil", 0.99, 25],
                [63401, "grizzly bear", None, 1],
                [3532, "rubber duck", 5.45, 24],
                [1523, None, 3.00, 6.8],
                [11765, "caviar", 67.95, None]
        ], True, False)
```

This "info" was passed to a function:

```
do_something(info)
```

The function was defined as follows:

```
do_something(data, header = False, index = False):
    do something with data
```

When I executed the code, I got an error : TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable.
This was because somewhere in the code I tried to loop over the two-dimensional array like this:

```
for row in data:
    for element in row:
        do something
```

However I found out, that "data" contains the whole tuple, not just the 2d-array causing this error when reaching "True". I was able to fix the problem calling the function like this:

```
do_something(*info)
```

This way the tuple gets unpacked correctly. However I am looking for a different solution since I might not be able to decide how the function gets called, so it should stay like this:

```
do_something(info)
```

I am also currently trying to understand WHY the data seems to "overlap". Meaning the positional arguments 1 and 2 (header and index) will correctly adress position 1 and 2 of the tuple that gets passed to the function. Header is True, Index is False (aside from this being the default). However the 0th positional argument "data" does not only contain the 0th element of the tuple, the 2d-array, but all of the data inside the info-tuple.

I had a look at some topics here on stack overflow and found the solution using * as well as some explanation how tuples work in function calls, as well as positional arguments in general, but i was unable to understand why the whole info tuple would end up inside the 0th positional argument "data" while "header" and "index" would work a expected, just pulling out parts of the tuple corresponding to their position.

Comment: Can you show us code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: `data` is the tuple `info`. That means `row` is successively the list, `True`, and `False`. I think you meant to call `do_something(info[0])`, so that only the nested list is passed to the function. Either that, or `for row in data[0]`.

Comment: @chepner I (partially) aware of that possibility. However my main problem is to understand  WHY data is (as you said) the entire tuple of info. I expected "data" to be just the two-dimensional array part since the first (or 0th) positional argument should also only contain the first (or 0th) element of the tuple, should it not?

Comment: `do_something(*info)` worked because the tuple was unpacked and `data` was assigned `info[0]`, `header` was assigned `info[1]`, and `index` assigned `info[2]`. With `do_something(info)`, `data` gets the *entire* tuple, and `header` and `index` get their default values.

Comment: There's no overlap, just the well-defined behavior of how tuple-unpacking works when you use the `*` syntax in the function call.

Comment: @chepner I see you are correct. I assumend header and index would get their values assigned from the info touple. However they where just default values, since nothing got unpacked at all. Thank you.